# Spring Boot 2.2.5 - Request method 'MOVE' not supported

Tags: spring-boot

I am playing around with a simple Spring Boot webapp which gets called by some software which does basic file download/upload tasks.

The software sending the Requests to my app can not be changed/modified and I came across following request being sent to my webapp:

```
DEBUG Received [
MOVE /database/1.tmp HTTP/1.1
Destination: http://localhost:8080/database/1
Host: localhost:8080

]
```

which results in

```
WARN Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'MOVE' not supported]
```

As I found out `MOVE` is not an enum in `RequestMethod` so I can not simply annotate my controller with `method = RequestMethod.MOVE`.

How can I handle this request?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to override Spring Boot's default firewall to allow `MOVE` methods:

```
@Bean
public HttpFirewall defaultHttpFirewall() {
    final StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    Set<String> allowedHttpMethods = new HashSet<>();
    allowedHttpMethods.add(HttpMethod.DELETE.name());
    allowedHttpMethods.add(HttpMethod.GET.name());
    allowedHttpMethods.add(HttpMethod.POST.name());
    allowedHttpMethods.add(HttpMethod.PUT.name());
    allowedHttpMethods.add("MOVE");
    firewall.setAllowedHttpMethods(allowedHttpMethods);
    return firewall;
}
```

Now that `MOVE` requests are handed over to your application, your only way (as I found out there are no controller mappings for custom methods) is to manually handle the requests in a filter:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class NonRESTFulHttpMethodRequestFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse servletResponse, final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        if ("MOVE".equals(httpServletRequest.getMethod())) {
            final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            log.trace("Ignoring 'MOVE {}' request with 200 OK", httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
    }
}
```